# Solution of System of Linear Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x' + y' - x - 2y = 2e^t$$
$$x' + y' - 3x - 4y = e^{2t}$$

I didn't do anything for this.
I found $Dx + Dy - 2x - 3y$...(*)..but nothing came.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $u = x + y: u' = x' + y'$. The equations can be rewritten as
$$u' - 2u + x = 2e^t\\u'-4u+x=e^{2t}$$

Now subtract the second equation from the first.
$$2u=2e^t-e^{2t}\\u=e^t-\dfrac{1}{2}e^{2t}$$

Now plug this value for $u$ into the first equation.
$$(e^t-e^{2t})-(2e^t-e^{2t})+x = 2e^t\\-e^t+x=2e^t\\x=3e^t$$

Now use this to find $y$.
$$3e^t + y = e^t-\dfrac{1}{2}e^{2t}\\y=-2e^t-\dfrac{1}{2}e^{2t}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that you have $x'+y'$ in both equations. Subtract both line and identify $x$ as a function of $y$, then work from there to get $y$.

Comment: really thanks can we say (x+y)' = x' + y' for this system to solve ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean here. You can substitute $u=x+y$ as @Stephen Donovan suggested.